# OBS studio - missing video parts after recording

Tags: obs

I captured a video with dual screen.
In File->Settings->Video there is Base (Canvas) Resolution 3840x1080 and Output (Scaled) Resolution 3840x1080.
In the Sources there is `Display Capture` 1920x1080 and `Display Capture 2` 1920x1080.

After recording before saving it has written something with `... overloaded ...` and the resulting video is missing some information (like every second, or third frame is dropped), so I can't see parts of a video.

Can I fix this?